# Pseudo-distributed hadoop dfs in docker. Trouble connecting from local machine to dfs

Tags: docker, hdfs

I've set up docker file that starts up a pseudo-distributed dfs when it runs. My goal is to test my spark app to see it is writing to the dfs correctly. But for starters, I'm just trying to run this command from local terminal to ensure I can connect to the dfs in the docker container from my local machine:

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/
```

When my core-site.xml looked like this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I would constantly get this error when I tried to connect via local hdfs-client: 
`ls: End of File Exception between local host is: "MacBook-Pro.local/192.168.0.4"; destination host is: "localhost":9000; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:`  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException

When I change the core-site.xml to look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

It worked fine and I was able to connect to the dfs from local machine.

I'm just wondering why.

Comment: i have the same question